# How to block the annoying “Before you continue” popup on Google?

Tags: cookies, privacy

Before it was possible to use Google with cookies disabled, or with extension [Cookie-AutoDelete](https://github.com/Cookie-AutoDelete/Cookie-AutoDelete/) or something similar.

For some weeks, this is gone. After each cookie deletion, I receive a popup that I have to "Accept".

> Before you continue
>
> Google uses cookies and other data to deliver, maintain, and improve our services and ads. If you agree, we’ll personalize the content and ads you see based on your activity on Google services like Search, Maps, and YouTube. We also have partners that measure how our services are used. Click “See more” to review your options or visit g.co/privacytools anytime.
>
> [I agree]

This means that we are basically forced to accept the all-mighty google cookie.

This is similar to the ["Sign-in to youtube" popup problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63680896/how-to-block-the-annoying-sign-in-to-youtube-popup)

How to avoid the "Before you continue" popup while keeping short-lived throwable Google cookies?

Note: [Google Consent Dialog Remover](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/google-consent-dialog-remover/?src=search) exists but does not work anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the following JavaScript to your browser through an extension (like Tampermonkey for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/)):

```javascript
// ==UserScript==
// @name         avoid Google's "before you continue"
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.2
// @description  How to block the annoying “Before you continue” popup on Google?
// @author       jonas
// @url          https://stackoverflow.com/a/63999294/1153476
// @match        https://www.google.com/*
// @grant        none
// @run-at       document-start
// ==/UserScript==

// This will remove the popup but there are some problems:
// Buttons and menus like 'More', 'Tools', and many others will not work
const style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerHTML = /* css */ `
  div[aria-modal] {
    display: none !important;
  }
`;
document.head.append(style);

// This solves the previous problems but it's probably not that great for privacy
const consentMatch = document.cookie.match(/CONSENT=(PENDING|YES)\+(\d+)/);
document.cookie=`CONSENT=YES+${consentMatch ? consentMatch[2] : '0'}; domain=.google.com`;
```

In Tampermonkey, on script `Settings` page, set `Run at` to `document-start`.

Comment: A similar trick also works for getting around login walls on news sites; inspect the page to find out the overlay name and set overflow on html and body for missing scrollbars. I'm pointing this out here just as an opportunity to stick it to the man.

Comment: FYI, Google has changed something, this Tampermonkey userscript does not work anymore.

Comment: I updated the script, it works now for consent in the modal.

Comment: This breaks the page: buttons, search suggestions, etc no longer work.

Answer (score 13):

Just block all of the cookies for the page where you see this popup and voilà.

[image: Open the View site information pane]

[image: Block all of the cookies that you see there]

Comment: Wow, that is really clever. This solution is enabling more privacy. I would upvote 10 times if i could

Comment: For people using Firefox, right-click the page, click 'View Page Info', go to the Permissions tab, and find 'Set Cookies'. There you can uncheck 'Use Default', and check Block.

Comment: This is great! Unfortunately, this doesn't prevent the "Sign in to Youtube" banner.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of Stepan, you can also add both domains (`google.com` and `www.google.com`) into the Google Group Policy settings.
You find this setting under: Google-Google Chrome-Content Settings-Block cookies on these sites.
This way you can push this company-wide.
Also, when your users are using `google.<countrycode>`, also add these. That helps the local google site users.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the userscript posted here has stopped working so here's a simpler version that does the trick for me :)

Direct link to install with tampermonkey:
https://gist.github.com/WoLpH/985a6072b35926eb4a3f9d2cdd0a2dad/raw/596925b09a38c1003cac97a3419db12e4b02f005/google-cookie-consent.user.js

If you have suggestions or questions: https://gist.github.com/WoLpH/985a6072b35926eb4a3f9d2cdd0a2dad

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Cookie Consent Remover
// @namespace    https://gist.github.com/WoLpH/985a6072b35926eb4a3f9d2cdd0a2dad
// @version      0.1
// @description  Remove Google's annoying cookie consent questions (especially annoying for Incognito windows)
// @author       Wolph
// @match        https://www.google.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

document.querySelector('div[aria-modal]').remove();
```